# SSIS OLEDB SQL Command Execution is slow

Tags: ssis

I have table with more than Million records.

1. When i execute my query in SSMS it takes around 1:24 less than 2 minutes for sure at any point of time and returns around 600,000 records.
2. SSIS takes more than couple of hours infact i was able to export it just once.

Here is the sample sql:

```
SELECT distinct 
A.Col1, A.Col2, A.Col3, A.Col4, A.Col5, A.Col6, A.Col7, B.Col3
FROM tblA  A
inner join tblB B on A.Col1 = B.col1 and 
A.Col2 = 'AB' AND A.Col3 Not In ('A','B','C') AND 
A.Col3 In ('FPC','FPE','PRN','SUB','RVW','FPO','FEV','PRM')
```

Note: Indexes do exists for all columns in select sql query (and for columns mentioned in where clause).

In SSIS,

1. I have Data Flow task on Control flow.
2. OleDB Source with SQL query command.
3. OleDB Destination tbl.

what might be causing delay in SSIS?

Comment: Is the SSIS execution host the same machine as the source and target servers, or is some part of this going over the network?

Comment: target server is going over or on network but it takes long time to execute the sql(SSIS execution host the same machine as the source).

Comment: Any suggestions?? I can't use Execute sql task here since source and target servers/db are different.

Comment: How is your OLE DB Destination configured? What is the table access mode set to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is most likely with your OLE DB Destination and the rate at which it can accept rows.  You can confirm this by testing a copy of your package with the OLE DB Destination removed.

Assuming that is the case, the most common reason is not using the "Fast Load" option in an OLE DB Destination delivering to SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience this could be one of two things:

1. This could be what's known as parameter-sniffing.  Which simply means that sometimes it binds a bad (slow) query plan to the query+parameters and because of caching this bad plan can become "stuck" and continually re-used for a particular application or use.  The way to detect this is to use the SQL Profiler to capture the query plan for your SSIS task's query and then compare it to the query plan of the fast-executing SSMS version.  If the query plans are significantly different, then you've probably got a parameter-sniffing problem.
2. However, for SSIS there is a more common problem (alluded to  by my comment/question and in Mike Honey's answer): Because SSIS uses a pipeline architecture, all you need is one slow component in the chain to stall the whole pipeline.  And one very common cause of slow components is not using the best task settings for the Data Flow Tasks.

The use of "Fast Load" is one possibility, however in my experience, there is another setting that is more commonly a problem for pipelining over networks, and that is "DefaultBufferMaxRows".  The default for this is 10,000, which I have invariably found to be way too high for network connections and should probably be between 100 and 1000 for these situations.

This is a property of the Destination DFT (Data Flow Task) in your Control Flow, so to change it just select that task's icon in the control Flow view.  You should see DefaultBufferMaxRows in the properties pane (under "Misc").  You may also want to lower "DefaultBufferSize" proportionately as well.